# How to calculate the pressure force on Magdeburg hemispheres?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, pressure, integration, fluid-statics

I have tried as below:
I choose surface element of hemisphere as $dA=r^2 d\theta d\varphi$,and force exerted on that is $dF=\Delta pdA\cos\theta\cos\varphi$，integrating leads to
$$r^2\Delta p\int_\frac{-\pi}{2}^\frac{\pi}{2} \cos\varphi \,d\varphi\int_\frac{-\pi}{2}^\frac{\pi}{2} \cos\theta \,d\theta$$
(Let θ be in the $xy$-plane which is perpendicular to the conjection line of two hemispheres and φ is the angle between $xy$-plane and some point on the surface of sphere)
What's wrong with my process? It would be better if a diagram is shown below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) You seem to be working in spherical polar co-ordinates, in which case the surface area element is $dA=r^2 \text{sin} \ \theta\ d \theta d \phi.\ $[Draw a diagram to see why. (I'm taking $\theta$ as the polar angle, the angle  between the $z$ axis and the radius finishing at the area element. My $z$ axis is perpendicular to the plane containing the junction-circle between the hemispheres.)

(2) The $\text{cos}\ \phi\ $shouldn't be there.

(3) But you do need to include a $\text{cos}\ \theta\ $ factor to give the $z$ component of the force. Components in other directions cancel with each other, as we consider area elements all round the hemisphere.

(4) You should be integrating between $\theta =0\ $ and $\theta =\frac{\pi}{2}\ $ as you want the force on a hemisphere.

(5) I hope you realise that, although this is a good exercise, you don't need to do all this in order to find the force of the atmosphere on a hemisphere. Just consider the projections of the area elements on to the x-y plane (the plane containing the junction-circle between the hemispheres)...

Comment: Your response helped me a lot! I checked my surface element and found it should have been r^2 cosφdφdθ by my choice of φ as you said. Everything else in my work is right and I work out right answer exactly! Intuitively I know the effective surface is the base of hemispheres. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Good! By the way, I think it's more common to use $\theta$ for the polar angle (the angle between the z axis and the radius to the point (P) in question) and $\phi$ for the azimuthal angle (the angle between the x axis and the radius to the foot of the perpendicular from P to the x-y plane).